# Data type DURATION fails for custom Google Data Studio connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio, timespan

I'm working on a custom connector for Google Datastudio, which connects to a specific API service following the [Google Data Studio Community Connectors](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector) documentation and the very nice article on [Building a custom Google Data Studio](https://medium.com/@bajena3/building-a-custom-google-data-studio-connector-from-a-z-part-1-basic-setup-445a6d965d3f).

Authentification via API key works. Handling of data schema and data fields works fine, too. And I'm retrieving and displaying data.

One of the remaining issues is the data type conversion. My original data comes with a field for duration in minutes. Google offers a data type for duration that is given in seconds. Therefore, I'm converting the minutes to seconds.

```
function getFields(request) {
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;

  fields.newDimension().setId('id').setName('ID').setType(types.NUMBER);
  fields.newDimension().setId('date').setName('Date').setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY);
  fields.newDimension().setId('user_id').setName('User ID').setType(types.NUMBER);
  fields.newDimension().setId('user').setName('User').setType(types.TEXT);

  //fields.newMetric().setId('time').setName('Time').setType(types.DURATION).setAggregation(aggregations.SUM);
  fields.newMetric().setId('time').setName('Time').setType(types.NUMBER).setAggregation(aggregations.SUM);
  fields.newMetric().setId('revenue').setName('Revenue').setType(types.CURRENCY_EUR).setAggregation(aggregations.SUM);

  fields.setDefaultDimension('user');
  fields.setDefaultMetric('time');

  return fields;
}
```

The [documentation on data types](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#datatype) that the duration is in seconds. So, the original data has 180min that convert to 10.800sec. If I return that data as `NUMBER` then it is correctly shown. If I then switch the data type in the UI to duration, it is automatically converted and shown as 03:00:00 (three hours = 180min = 10.800sec). But when I return the original data as `DURATION` the connector will fail and the UI won't work.

Any idea how to correctly convert and set data for type `DURATION`?

Answer (score 2):

You will find it crazy, but it works:

You have to return the duration as a string representing the number of seconds.

```
case 'DURATION':
      row.push((value===null) ? null : Number.parseInt(value).toString());
      break;
```

That worked for me ;)

Comment: Yeah, found that solution too :) crazy stuff